# Possible to slide next div in without scrolling through all divs?

Tags: jquery

Just finishing up a scroll div using tabs but trying to figure out a way of making it so that for example you click link 4 and instead of the script scrolling through all divs to get to number 4 i would like it so it scrolls out div1 and scrolls in div4

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cC4tU/1/

jquery

```
$.extend($.easing,
 {
     easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
    }

    });
//EXPAND PAGE DIV CONTENT
$(".tab_item").hover(function(){
         var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg");
        $(background).stop().animate({
            left: $(this).position()['left']
        }, {
            duration: 700, easing: 'easeInOutElastic'
        });
    });

var TabbedContent = {
    init: function() {    
        $(".tab_item").click(function() {
            var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg");
            $(background).stop().animate({
                left: $(this).position()['left']
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
            TabbedContent.slideContent($(this));
        });
    },

    slideContent: function(obj) {
        var margin = $(obj).parent().parent().find(".slide_content").width();
        margin = margin * ($(obj).prevAll().size() - 1);
        margin = margin * -1;
        $(obj).parent().parent().find(".tabslider").stop().animate({
            marginLeft: margin + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 1500, easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });
    }
}
TabbedContent.init();
```

Comment: can someone point me in the right direction, or is this not possible? was thinking it may have to be done with ajax but then you might get loading times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dwhizz, what you want is certainly possible.

I'm not going to write it for you but as far as I can tell, all changes will be in `slideContent`.

Strategy :

- Hide all tabslider elements except current and new
- Calculate margin based on the two visible items
- Animate (probably no change)
- Remember current tabslider element for next time.

Comment: ok thanks for the guidelines will get to work, not sure if i can squeeze any more power out of me! seems complex

Comment: Dwhizz, I said I wouldn't write it for you but ... if you want to cheat, see **[this update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC4tU/3/)**. Calculating the margin was harder than I thought. Note I made changes to the HTML and CSS as well as the javascript.

Comment: LMAO, lol, its 6 in the morning been trying all night, dont think i would have got that working but it is a great eye opener on how you are doing it thank you kindly sir. will study it now thanks again